WMS service basic authentication
I am building a leaflet map on a server without root access.
I'd like to add a WMS service which is secured by basic authentication(username and password).
There is a simple method in leaflet adding WMS services with L.tileLayer.wms but this does not work for secured WMS services. So is there a way I can authenticate at the wms server and receive the WMS tiles and parse them to leaflet? Adding the login credentials to the WMS URL (f.e. https://username:password@wmsserver.com)does not work for me.

You could use this plugin: https://github.com/ticinum-aerospace/leaflet-wms-header.

Thanks Thomas. I came across the his one as well, but how would I implement the username and password? It seems this plugin works for authentication keys out of the box.

When using basic authentication, you pass username and password in the header to the server:
Authorization: Basic <credentials>

<credentials> is the Base64 encoded username and password joined by a single colon :.
You could use leaflet-wms-header to pass along a custom header. Unfortunately, I don't have any WMS server with basic authentication at hand for testing but here is an example based on the example provided by leaflet-wms-header:
// untested code

var wmsLayer = L.TileLayer.wmsHeader(
    'https://GEOSERVER_PATH/geoserver/wms?',
    {
        layers: 'YOUR_LAYER',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true,
    },
    [
        { 
            header: 'Authorization', 
            value: `Basic ${btoa(username + ':' + password)}` 
        },
    ],
    null
).addTo(map);

(btoa encodes the given string to a Base64 encoded string.)

Thanks a lot for elaborating Thomas, this works right away!
